# PHP export to .DBF file

Tags: php, export, dbf

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to export in .dbf file extension using php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php

Comment: http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html

Comment: thanks for the the help,but I have another question on how to use the function dbase_create()?,Because im trying to use it and i already configure the php.ini located in xammp\xammp\apache\bin\php.ini,and i already remove the comment tag in extension = php_dbase.dll and i also restarted my apache but it still dont work.any idea what i have done wrong?Im using php v 5.3.5,thanks